# List of image sizes

Tags: images, automation

I have a folder with hundreds of images. I would like to obtain a list of their dimensions (width, height) without having to manually check each image. Something similar to this:

```
image001.jpg, 1024, 768
```

How can do I this (Mac/*nix solution preferred)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php):

```
identify -format "%f, %w, %h\n" *.jpg
```

or

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -exec identify -format "%d/%f, %w, %h" {} \;
```

Comment: +1, more tidy than my answer :) figured imagemagick could do it

Answer (score 0):

use file.

"file *.jpg"

to process it you could always do something like

```
for i in `ls *.jpg`
do
output=`file $i`
res=`echo $output | cut -d "," -f2`
name=`echo $output | cut -d ":" -f1`
echo $name $res
done
```

or use awk or something similar to process the output of file, but either way it should do the job.

Comment: Don't use `\`ls\`` in `for`. Just use the glob pattern directly.

Comment: On my system, `file` doesn't output the size for JPEG files.

Comment: hmm, worth knowing.